# when app install from playstore show a dialog for accept

Tags: android

> can i hide this dialog from playstore [image]
>
> If it possible then please share me.

Comment: It show mainly in case of some specified permissions.

Comment: If you increase your `targetSdkVersion` to 23 or above, this dialog should no longer be shown on devices running Android 6.0 or above. You will then, however, need to show dialogs to the user whenever you're about to perform an action that requires a permission that your app doesn't already have.

Comment: ok sir, i got it and i have checked it with pratical. thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can i hide this dialog from playstore.

**YES** to remove that dialog than you need to set `targetSdkVersion` 23 or above than it will be not shown on devices running Android 6.0 or above

> If it possible then please share me.

make `targetSdkVersion` above than 23

Comment: but in some application its hide and direct installing start

Comment: So can you give me exact reason for that.

Comment: @JatinBansal if you targetSdkVersion to 23 or above than this dialog will display

Comment: yes sir i got result and thank you sir for get solution me .

Comment: @JatinBansal happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

never you can't remove you can change this by increasing or decreasing the number of permissions in your app.

Comment: thanks sir , i got exact reason for showing this dialog